# PMD Memory Leak

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, pmd, java-memory-leaks

I have a serious memory leak when using pmd in eclipse on windows. I import a bunch of large maven projects. After m2e and compilation PMD starts up. It then eventually runs in about 8-10 eclipse job instances in parallel for the many (about 50) projects in the workspace. Then the process size grows endlessly until virtual memory on the machine is exhausted (at about 12 GB or so) and the PC completely freezes.

My memory config in eclipse.ini:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2G
-Xss2m
-Xverify:none
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G
```

The heap size limit here of 2 GB doesn't seem to have much effect. I suspect then that the allocated vm memory is not the java heap but classloader metaspace or from a native dll.

I've got 32 GB RAM on my machine. Using java 1.8.0_121.

Here's a vmmap snapshot shortly before the process gets dangerously large and I have to kill it:

[image: memory snapshot]

I tried running `jcmd PID GC.class_stats` against the process, but I don't see the problem here, since total bytes is only ~1.4 GB:

```
1636:
Index Super  InstBytes KlassBytes annotations    CpAll MethodCount Bytecodes MethodAll    ROAll     RWAll     Total ClassName
    1    89  141004480        560           0     1296           7       149      2176      880      3464      4344 java.util.HashMap$Node
    2    -1  131125856        480           0        0           0         0         0       24       584       608 [I
    3    89  129135744        624           0     8712          94      4623     58024    12136     56304     68440 java.lang.String
    4    -1  111470376        480           0        0           0         0         0       24       584       608 [B
    5    -1   94462520        480           0        0           0         0         0       24       584       608 [C
    6    -1   55019976        480           0        0           0         0         0       32       584       616 [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
    7    -1   53828832        480           0        0           0         0         0       24       584       608 [Ljava.lang.Object;
    8    89   51354560        504           0     9016          42      2757     23352     6976     26704     33680 java.net.URL
    9    89   48028392        504           0      544           1        20       496      216      1520      1736 java.util.LinkedList$Node
   10 28783   40910880       1000           0     6864          51      3951     35648     8664     35792     44456 java.util.HashMap
...snip...
48234 48225          0        608           0      288           2        10       288      160      1152      1312 sun.util.resources.en.CalendarData_en
48235 48225          0        608           0      360           2        27       304      200      1200      1400 sun.util.resources.en.CurrencyNames_en_US
48236 48225          0        608           0      288           2        10       288      160      1152      1312 sun.util.resources.en.LocaleNames_en
48237 48229          0        608           0      288           2        10       304      176      1152      1328 sun.util.resources.en.TimeZoneNames_en
48238 29013          0        520           0      272           2         5       592      160      1352      1512 sun.util.spi.CalendarProvider
48239    89          0        512           0      336           3         5       440      240      1184      1424 sun.util.spi.XmlPropertiesProvider
48240    89          0        560           0      440           5        16       760      488      1504      1992 sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider$EH
48241    89          0        528           0     1040           3        71       520      464      1840      2304 sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider$Resolver
48242    89          0        552           0      520           3        19       512      456      1392      1848 uescape.view.UnicodeEscapeView$1
48243    89          0        552           0      520           3        19       512      456      1392      1848 uescape.view.UnicodeEscapeView$2
        1374367440   32457872      432408 90295960      502480  22001616 144854704 85034192 198366896 283401088 Total
            485.0%      11.5%        0.2%    31.9%           -      7.8%     51.1%    30.0%     70.0%    100.0%
Index Super  InstBytes KlassBytes annotations    CpAll MethodCount Bytecodes MethodAll    ROAll     RWAll     Total ClassName
```

I don't have much experience profiling native processes on Windows. How can I determine what's endlessly allocating so much memory?

Comment: [Which PMD Eclipse plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/pmd) do you have in which version? Check the bug tracker of PMD and of the plug-in for known issues (e. g. [PDM issue #213](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/213)).

Comment: Using pmd-eclipse-plugin 4.0.15, pmd 5.3.5 and maven-pmd-plugin 3.6. I see now all are somewhat out of date and could use an upgrade, especially pmd itself, I just need to check compatibility with Oxygen 2. The link to Eclipse Marketplace doesn't seem to have the latest pmd-eclipse-plugin: https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin

Comment: @scorciatoia Don't worry about Eclipse Marketplace - just download version 4.0.17 of pmd-eclipse-plugin from github using the link in your comment.

Comment: 4.0.17 is not a release ;-)

Comment: I upgraded pmd-eclipse plugin to 4.0.16.v20180412-0833, which contains PMD 6.2.0, but didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a problem of the pmd-eclipse-plugin.
See https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/issues/52

The latest version [4.0.17.v20180801-1551](https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/releases/tag/4.0.17.v20180801-1551) contains a fix.

It is available via the update site: https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/